# cgSceneGraph text clipping and wordwrap

Tags: text, release, clipping

I used text node as child od node to implement align support. 
It's possible to do text clipping ? I text is bigger and parent node element.
And also I need to implement word wrapping.

I heard about new 2.0 - It seems this release has implemented som of this. Someone know something about date of 2.0. release ?

Answer (score 0):

regarding v2, you may already download current version on the WIP branch on GitHub.
It's still not finished (we add new samples and unexpected features and options, so we we have lost some time), but it's already stable and used on some customers projects. Time-to-time we add new things inside :)

Regarding your request, relationship between a parent node and its children is only related to transformation. That means that only transformations (scale, rotation, translation) applied to a parent will be applied to the child. Nothing regarding the size. So you cannot use it to directly align your nodes.
Anyway, you may easily develop it: you know the size of your text and your parent (using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods) and their positions so you can translate the text node to be aligned with another node.

To use the word wrapping, you may use the `myTextNode.setWrapMode(CGSGWrapMode.WORD, true)` call.
There is also `CGSGWrapMode.LETTER` (default) and `CGSGWrapMode.SENTENCE`.

Hope this help.